# is it possible to create a tar of any file which will give different file name after untar

Tags: linux, tar

I have some files to tar
for example
 
abc.php_mtime_size
now i want to TAR this file such that when I untar it will have a name "abc.php"
so is there any way by which I can specify output file name as well while creating the TAR file.

Comment: Why this question has `ruby` tag?

Comment: I removed the Ruby tag.

Comment: Can you be more clear?  You have some files, and you want to tar them. So when you tar them, they become x.tar and when you untar, it gets unpacked into the original filenames.  Are you having directory of files...?

Comment: In the meantime, check this SO thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring

Comment: I have a hierarchical structure of files and all the files are in "abc.php_mtime_size" this format i.e filename_mtime_size. Now when tar file is created, can i specify the output file name?

Comment: I want to  store files under differing names in the archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following set/sequence of commands:
assuming your original file is a.b_backup...you can try this..

```
$ tar -cvf test.tar a.b_backup
$ tar --transform='s/_backup//' -xf test.tar
$ ls
a.b
a.b_backup
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should rename the file to its desired name before you tar it.

Comment: I can do that, but it will not solve my purpose. I want to give the output file name while creating TAR file itself.